# Logitech M545 button mapping

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, logitech

I bought a Logitech M545 yesterday, and it's not behaving as it should. With my old M705 I could use the thumb buttons to go back/forwards in Firefox, Thunar, etc, but with the M545 they don't even send the normal codes for button presses. Here's what I get:

Back button:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 7968516, (47,78), root:(3157,978),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 7968516, (47,78), root:(3157,978),
    state 0x50, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 7968524, (47,78), root:(3157,978),
    state 0x50, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 7968530, (47,78), root:(3157,978),
    state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Forwards button:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 7969328, (47,78), root:(3157,978),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7000001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 7969436, (47,78), root:(3157,978),
    state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I've tried with both Debian and Ubuntu vivid, several different kernels.

How can I remap these buttons to get the behaviour I'm used to, and how do I differentiate between them and keyboard presses? Also, since both buttons send Super_L, how can I tell them apart?

If remapping means I lose Super_L from the keyboard, then so be it, although it's not ideal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have to run a Logitech utility to reprogram the buttons in such case. Works fine through VirtualBox.

(from the experience with my G300 and the fact that the description of M545 says that it is programmable)

Another possibility is the **evrouter** daemon. It can change the events from input devices on the fly. Can be used to fix the problem or extend the functionality of the buttons even more.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I was really hoping to avoid having to resort to a Windows VM, but I guess I will have to try that for a permanent fix. I was not aware of evrouter, and will definitely check that out. All that said, Logitech should really not make hardware (especially not mice) that only works with Windows. I recommend other Linux users not to buy this mouse, and I've voiced my concerns to Logitech.

Answer (score 2):

I just made a [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/CzBiX/logitech-m560/tree/m545), that provide the driver for M560/M545/M546.

Just download it, and checkout source to the right kernel version, and run `make && sudo make install`. Then you can use `xbindkeys-config` to mapping it.

Answer (score 1):

I (sort of) managed to work it out.

Create "/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-logitech-m-545.hwdb" with the following:

```
# Logitech M545
keyboard:usb:v046DpC52B*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70007=back
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700E3=forward
```

Then:

```
udevadm hwdb --update
```

Unplug the receiver and plug it back in, and the thumb buttons now behave normally at least in firefox.

This is only a workaround as it still sends keyboard events, but it does what I mainly want it to do.

EDIT: fix code